# Tensorflow custom model training! failed to Create/Open: : The system cannot find the path specified. ; No such process

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I get an error when I try to run train.py from the object_detection API. Any ideas?
I used Tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0

Here is the whole error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 185, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\***\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\***\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\***\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\***\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 109, in main
    overwrite=True)
  File "C:\Users\***\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 469, in copy
    copy_v2(oldpath, newpath, overwrite)
  File "C:\Users\***\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 486, in copy_v2
    compat.as_bytes(src), compat.as_bytes(dst), overwrite)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open:  : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process
```

I've been trying to fix this for a few hours but just can't get it to work!

Maybe someone knows how to fix this error. thanks